# Css-translate & z-index

Tags: css, css-position, transform, centering

I've a problem here
In the body of the html file there is this:
`<div>translate() issue</div>`
And I wanted to implement this shape by css:
[HTML + CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xUHB.png)
So this is how I made it:

```
div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #03a9f4;

        margin: 40px auto;
        position: relative;
}

div::before {
        content: "";
        background-color: #03a9f4;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
        z-index: -1;
}

div::after {
        content: "";
        background-color: #e91e63;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(5deg);
        z-index: -2;
}
```

And it worked actually, then I wanted to center the div using position and translate() like this:

```
div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Instead of autoing the margin left and right,
but,
the 'z-index' of div::before and div::after is not working anymore, because of transform property.
Is there any solution or idea to use both of them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The `transform` property causes the `<div>` to be a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context). This means the pseudo-elements within are contained inside the `<div>` element, meaning the `<div>` element cannot be in front of the pseudo-elements, so the `<div>` element's background color cannot be drawn on top of the pseudo-elements.

Instead, you could consider having another element inside the `<div>`, that *can* draw on top of the pseudo-elements:

```css
div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 40px auto;
        position: relative;
}

p {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #03a9f4;
}


div::before {
        content: "";
        background-color: #03a9f4;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
        z-index: -1;
}

div::after {
        content: "";
        background-color: #e91e63;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: rotate(5deg);
        z-index: -2;
}

div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div><p>translate() issue</p></div>
```